# Amazon Sagemaker Failed: Please check if you have a directory that has same name as the git repo?

Tags: github, amazon-sagemaker

I was working in Sagemaker, and noticed that my notebook instance was behind my github repo as I had just pushed to it outside of working in Sagemaker. I couldn't seem to pull, so I deleted the directory within Jupyter and git cloned my updated repo. It worked fine, but once I was done working I haven't since been able to reinitialize the notebook. Sagemaker simpy says

> **Failure reason**
>
> Please check if you have a directory that has same name as the git repo.

I cloned from the same repo, so I don't imagine that the directory name changed. Maybe the directory is in the wrong place? Either way, how do I go in and change things if I can't open the notebook? Not sure what to do about this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lifecycle configuration (LCC) script that clones the repository? I can't think of another reason why the notebook would fail to start (I assume what you meant by 'reinitialize'). If you do, remove the LCC script to start your notebook. Or you could add a condition to check for the folder and clone if it does not exist, something like -

```
if [ ! -d "$FOLDER" ] ; then
    git -C /home/sagemaker-user clone $REPOSITORY_URL
# if you want to pull latest when restarting, uncomment lines below
# else
#     cd "$FOLDER"
#     git pull $REPOSITORY_URL
fi
```

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.